# Cannot load translator in embedded Qt

Tags: qt, internationalization, arm, qt4, beagleboneblack

### Problem

I need to translate a Qt 4.8.6 application that runs on a BeagleBone Black. Here is the code of a simple test that I can't get to run:

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTranslator      translator;
    QString          file(a.applicationDirPath() + "/test_pt_BR.qm");

    qDebug() << "Translation file:" << file;
    qDebug() << "File exists:     " << QFile::exists(file);
    qDebug() << "translator.load: " << translator.load(file);

    qDebug() << translator.translate("global", "Testing translation functionality in Qt.");

    return a.exec();
}
```

Having included `TRANSLATIONS += test_pt_BR.ts` in my .pro file, I'm able to run the *lupdate* tool successfully. In the generated file, I manually edited only the `<translation>` tag.

**test_pt_BR.ts**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.0" language="pt_BR">
<context>
    <name>global</name>
    <message>
        <location filename="main.cpp" line="15"/>
        <source>Testing translation functionality in Qt.</source>
        <translation>Testando a funcionalidade de tradução no Qt.</translation>
    </message>
</context>
</TS>
```

I'm able to run the *lrelease* tool successfully as well. The `test_pt_BR.qm` file is deployed into the same folder as the application executable. Here is the printed output:

```
Translation file: "/root/TranslationTest/test_pt_BR.qm" 
File exists:      true 
translator.load:  false 
""
```

As it seems to me, the translation file is located at the right place, but Qt cannot load it correctly. The `QTranslator::load()` method only returns a boolean, so I can't see exactly what's wrong.

### Another approach

To make sure that the problem is not about finding or opening the right file, I tried using another overload of QTranslator::load().

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTranslator      translator;
    QFile            file(a.applicationDirPath() + "/test_pt_BR.qm");
    QByteArray       data;

    qDebug() << "Translation file:" << file.fileName();
    qDebug() << "File open:       " << file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);

    data = file.readAll();

    qDebug() << "File size:       " << data.size();
    qDebug() << "translator.load: " << translator.load((uchar*) data.data(), data.size());

    qDebug() << translator.translate("global", "Testing translation functionality in Qt.");

    return a.exec();
}
```

The same problem appears to occur:

```
Translation file: "/root/TranslationTest/test_pt_BR.qm" 
File open:        true 
File size:        196 
translator.load:  false 
""
```

---

One detail that might be related: when I installed the Qt framework, in an Ubuntu environment, I couldn't compile the linguist tools, except for *lrelease*. The only way I could get *lupdate* was to run the configure script without the `-embedded arm` option, which I used in order to develop applications that run on the BeagleBone Black. So, even though the *lupdate* tool is running normally, I'm not sure if it is "compatible" with Qt embedded.

Comment: Why don't just give the filename to the [QTranslator::load](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtranslator.html#load) function ? The problem could be in your casting from QByteArray to uchar*

Comment: @ymoreau Yes, I did that, same problem. I think that if the problem was in the casting, then my first approach should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I still couldn't get `QTranslator::load()` to work, so I used another strategy: I coded a `CustomTranslator` class, derived from `QTranslator`. The `QTranslator::translate()` method is virtual, so I was able to override it to return the hardcoded strings that I put inside my class.

It isn't the perfect solution, but I'm pretty satisfied that I can install this `CustomTranslator` in my application, so that the translatable texts in the designer get translated automatically. If I'm able to solve the `QTranslator::load()` problem in the future, I'll just need to swap the translators to make it work.